# git push --follow-tags on the filtered repository

Tags: git, bamboo, rush

looking for help with fallowing problem:
I have huge repository with huge history (+2GB), to solve problem with CI build times, an amount of data transfer I started to use some workarounds. I want to use shallow clone but I'm not able as some of my tools (rush.js) requires history.
I was able to configure Atlassian Bamboo CI to work with script like:

```
# THIS IS PART CONTROLLED BY CI - we do not control this part
# and do not know exact commands but checkout script looks something like:
git init
git fetch -f -p ssh://... +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master --update-head-ok -q --depth 1
git remote add origin ssh://...
git checkout

# My script - workaround - so simple unshallow but filter out trees, 
# to limit amount of retrieved objects
git remote set-url origin https://...
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
git fetch --filter=tree:0 --unshallow

# THIS PART IS CONTROLLED BY RUSH.JS - we do not control this script
# it is behind some of commands which we need to use (rush publish, rush version)
git checkout -b version/bump-1
git add :/*
git commit -m "Applying package updates. [skip ci]" --no-verify
git push origin HEAD:version/bump-1 --follow-tags --verbose --no-verify
```

Unfortunately similar script works in different way locally and on Jenkins CI.
The last `git push` starts to download some additional data (trees, blobs ?), and this looks like:

```
Pushing to https://...
remote: Enumerating objects: 133170, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (14533/14533), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (716/716), done.
remote: Total 133170 (delta 14027), reused 13817 (delta 13817), pack-reused 118637
Receiving objects: 100% (133170/133170), 12.05 MiB | 5.23 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (88403/88403), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 129054, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (14090/14090), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (733/733), done.
.. and the same again and again and again ....
```

Push without `--follow-tags`  flag works locally as expected, but this is out of control, and I'm not able to disable that flag. I do not know what is specific for Bamboo, but there, such scripts works perfectly. Same version of Git. When looking to the `.git` folder on Bamboo, and comparing to local one I do not see important differences.
The `.git/config` on Bamboo is :

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 1
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    promisor = true
    partialclonefilter = tree:0
```

and local one is:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 1
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    promisor = true
    partialclonefilter = tree:0
```

Maybe someone have some suggestions?